# How to save the content in text file using php

Tags: php

when i click submit button i want to save the content in different file
for example if i click the first time the file name should be 1.1.txt 
if i click second time i want to save the content in 1.2.txt,third time 1.3.txt,etc..
so each time click the submit button the file name should be different

Here is my code,this code is wrong..

```
<?
$a_str = array($_POST["content"]);
$a_url = $_POST["url"];
 $contents = implode(PHP_EOL ,$a_str);
$contents .= PHP_EOL .PHP_EOL;
$d='1.1';

for ($n=0; $n<6; $n++) {
 file_put_contents($d.txt, $contents);
 $d='1.'+$n;
 }
print("$contents");
?>
```

please help me How to do it?

Comment: Why does you write `$a_str = array($_POST["content"]);`?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the current value in session. Try this

```
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['count']))
    $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
else
    $_SESSION['count']++;

$contents = implode(PHP_EOL, array($_POST['content']));
file_put_contents('1.'.$_SESSION['count'].'.txt', $contents);

print($contents);
```

Comment: it's not work for me,any other way to do it?the file getting generating 14.txt,15.txt,etc..but i want 1.1.txt,1.2.txt,etc..

Comment: If you are not in session you could save the counter in a file as reported by @Alireza Fallah

Answer (score 0):

Try this, every time you save the contents, the counter increase one.and the counter holds the file name. this way is safer than using session or cookie, because in that way if your session or cookie expires, the counter will be reset, and the old files will be overwritten

```
$a_str = array($_POST["content"]);
$a_url = $_POST["url"];
$contents = implode(PHP_EOL, $a_str);
$contents .= PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$filename = file_get_contents("counter.txt");
$counter = file_exists('counter.txt') ? file_get_contents("counter.txt")+1 : 1 ;
file_put_contents("1.".$counter.".txt",$contents);
file_put_contents("counter.txt",$counter);
```

Comment: first time it's generating 1.1.txt,if i click second time the 1.1.txt file getting modified,and it's not generating 1.2.txt..how to fix it?